# Bootstrap 3 - Putting images next to each other with text on top

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for a way in Bootstrap 3 to keep putting images next to each other horizontally with text on top for each image that sticks with that image. Also, if the row should meet the end of the page, the image would then continue on the next line along with its corresponding text.

So for example,

```
Text 1  Text 2  Text 3

IMG 1   IMG 2   IMG 3 ...

Text 12 Text 13

IMG 12  IMG 13 ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Start with a row class then use the col-sm-1 or 2 class, mess with the left and right margins until you get them to touch. The can probably be added by grouping it inside the col span divs.

If you would like a code example, please post what you have so far and we can go from there.